# How do I delete directories where I've used pnpm to install packages?

Tags: pnpm

Dos' `del /S /F /Q tstpkg` doesn't error, but it leaves the files.

Gnuwin32's `rm` gives the result below...

I need to bring up windows explorer to get it to go away. Is there any e.g. `pnpm clean-up-after-yourself` command that I've missed?

```
c:/srv/work> rm -rf tstpkg                                                                    
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/@jridgewell+trace-mapping@0.3.25/node_modules/@jridgewell' to `resolve-uri': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/@jridgewell+trace-mapping@0.3.25/node_modules/@jridgewell' to `sourcemap-codec': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/@nodelib+fs.walk@1.2.8/node_modules/@nodelib' to `fs.scandir': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.2_svelte@5.0.0-next.85_vite@5.2.6/node_modules/@sveltejs' to `vite-plugin-svelte-inspector': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/brace-expansion@1.1.11/node_modules' to `balanced-match': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/chokidar@3.6.0/node_modules' to `anymatch': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/chokidar@3.6.0/node_modules' to `braces': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.20.2/node_modules/@esbuild' to `win32-x64': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/esrap@1.2.1/node_modules/@jridgewell' to `sourcemap-codec': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/esrap@1.2.1/node_modules/@types' to `estree': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/fast-glob@3.3.2/node_modules/@nodelib' to `fs.stat': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/fast-glob@3.3.2/node_modules/@nodelib' to `fs.walk': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/glob@7.2.3/node_modules' to `fs.realpath': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/is-binary-path@2.1.0/node_modules' to `binary-extensions': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/is-glob@4.0.3/node_modules' to `is-extglob': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/is-reference@3.0.2/node_modules/@types' to `estree': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/magic-string@0.30.8/node_modules/@jridgewell' to `sourcemap-codec': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/micromatch@4.0.5/node_modules' to `braces': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/minimatch@3.1.2/node_modules' to `brace-expansion': No such file or directory
rm: cannot chdir from `tstpkg/node_modules/.pnpm/mkdirp@0.5.6/node_modules' to `minimist': No such file or directory
```